# Magento 2 - Replacing an injected argument via constructor throws an error

Tags: magento2, object-manager

I am trying to replace an argument via configuration file (di.xml)that's been injected in constructor but it throws an error. Any help will be appreciated

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mage2\VirtualTypes\Model\Device::__construct() must be an instance of Mage2\VirtualTypes\Model\Apple, instance of Mage2\VirtualTypes\Model\Android given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /var/www/html/app/code/Mage2/VirtualTypes/Model/Device.php:15
>   Stack trace:

I removed var/generation, var/di and var/cache folders but it doesn't help. Here is my code sample

```
class Device implements DeviceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Apple
     */
    protected $apple;

    /**
     * Device constructor.
     * @param Apple $apple
     */
    public function __construct(Apple $apple)
    {
        $this->apple = $apple;
    }
}
```

di.xml file

`<type name="Mage2\VirtualTypes\Model\Device">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="apple" xsi:type="object">Mage2\VirtualTypes\Model\Android</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>`

And Android class looks like

```
class Android
{
    /**
     * @var AndroidList
     */
    protected $androidList;

    /**
     * Android constructor.
     * @param AndroidList $androidList
     */
    public function __construct(AndroidList $androidList)
    {
        $this->androidList = $androidList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Android class must be inherite from Apple class.

Comment: Ah thank you @SohelRana. I forgot to extend it from Apple class

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to extend the Android class from Apple and below is the correct sample code

```
class Device implements DeviceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Apple
     */
    protected $apple;

    /**
     * Device constructor.
     * @param Apple $apple
     */
    public function __construct(Apple $apple)
    {
        $this->apple = $apple;
    }
}
```

di.xml file

`<type name="Mage2\VirtualTypes\Model\Device">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="apple" xsi:type="object">Mage2\VirtualTypes\Model\Android</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>`

Android class

```
class Android extends Apple
{
    /**
     * @var AndroidList
     */
    protected $androidList;

    /**
     * Android constructor.
     * @param AndroidList $androidList
     */
    public function __construct(AndroidList $androidList)
    {
        $this->androidList = $androidList;
    }
}
```